# Is it possible to populate a ListView with a TwoLineListItem?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a ListView with items that have two lines of text, one line with a larger font than the other. TwoLineListItem seems to be what I need, but the app crashes whenever I try to run the activity like that. Any suggestions?

```
<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:mode="twoLine"
>       
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
/>

<TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
/>
</TwoLineListItem>
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:mode="twoLine"
>       
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
/>      
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
/>
</TwoLineListItem>
```

Comment: You have any code to show us?

Comment: yeah, just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would inflate `android.R.layout.two_line_list_item` in your `getView()` method and bind your values to that. The TextView ids in that layout are `android.R.id.text1` and `android.R.id.text2`. Below is an example of a getView() that gets close to what you want.

```
        public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, null);
            }

            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setText("Big Font Text");

            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            text.setText("Small Font Text");
            return view;
        }
```